# Port forwarding doesn't work, still shows router page

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding

I'm toying around with setting up port forwarding on my home router. I couldn't get it to work, though. Here is what I tried:

When I opened my router's public IP address in my browser, it pulled up the MikroTik RouterOS page. I then opened up 192.168.1.1 in my browser, logged in, and set port 80 to be forwarded to my computer at 192.168.xxx.xxx, where Apache is running. After this, when I opened the public IP again, I got the same RouterOS page. (I have a TP-Link wireless router.)

I also tried forwarding port 8080, and I started Apache connected to port 8080, but when I tried viewing it in the browser, I got a 'could not connect' error.

I checked the port with an online tool, and it doesn't seem to be blocked.

It seems like port forwarding doesn't do anything. It's almost as if the browser is getting a connection to the wrong router, though that seems impossible.

What could be causing this?

Comment: I know the pain of not knowing what is going on. I've been there and i am pretty sure you did not rebooted the router after making changes. Do it please and let me know if my answer is correct. Am i right about reboot? Use the power switch.

Comment: @mnmnc I rebooted from the control panel, but that didn't fix it.

Comment: Do you have two routers? Can you "tracert 8.8.8.8" and show us the results. We only need the first 3 hops.

Comment: @NitroxDM The first IP is 192.168.1.1. When I browse to the second IP, I get the same result as opening my public IP (the RouterOS page). The third IP is also very similar to my public IP. Does this mean my router is in a sub-network controlled by a router at the ISP?

Comment: sub-network - yes but that isn't your issue. How are your MikroTik and TP-Link connected? And where is the server connected?

Comment: Can you make us a chart of your network? https://www.lucidchart.com/

Comment: @NitroxDM SERVER --> wireless <-- TP-Link ROUTER --> wired <-- ANTENNA --> wireless | From here on, I don't know, and don't have access. The MikroTik router is somewhere out here.

Comment: Like this? https://www.lucidchart.com/documents/edit/4a6b-faac-50ec7139-a57b-76250a6e6711#?demo=on

Comment: @NitrokDM No, I'm pretty sure the MikroTik router is somewhere on the other end of the wireless WAN connection. There's no wired connection between the two routers.

Comment: Go ahead and up date the chart. So you don't own the MikroTik router. Correct?

Answer (score 0):

With your current ISP's set up you can't. Call them and ask for a static IP. If they will give you that you might be in business.